# Easy system of equations?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Given the system of equations find $ v_3,v_4$ . If you only know the value of $ v_1,v_2$
$p_0+p=p_1$
$p_1+p=p_2$
$p_0+2p=p_3$
$p_3+p=p_4$
$p_1v_1 = p_2v_2 = p_3v_3 = p_4v_4$
Came to the equations when solving a complex physics task.
Found that I don't know the method of solving such problems.
I hope you will tell me one. Tried a lot of summing, subtracting equations one from each other, making substitutions, but did not succeded.
Thanks for help.

Comment: do you have a typo as $$p_1 + p = p2 = p3$$?

Comment: The unknown variables to find are v3 and v4. We know koefficents v1, v2. The other are unknown variables, that we dont need to find

Comment: No, i checked, it seems like no typos are there.

Comment: if that is true and the statement I made earlier is true..then $$v_2 = v_3$$ then you have some interesting behavior..

Comment: Oh that is very possible in this physical system

Comment: with a background in physics in my back pocket, can you humor me and let me know what area of physics this is?

Comment: This is molecular physics : pressures of gases and their volumes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first four linear equations have the solution
$$
p=p_4-p_3,\; p_0=3p_3 - 2p_4,\; p_1=2p_3 - p_4,\;
p_2=p_3
$$
with free parameters $p_3,p_4$. This follows just by adding and subtracting the equations. We can substitute this result to the system of polynomial equations
$$
p_1v_1-p_2v_2=0, \; p_2v_2-p_3v_3=0, \; p_3v_3-p_4v_4=0.
$$
Assume first that$p_3,p_4\neq 0$. Then it follows that
$$
v_3=v_2,\; v_4= \frac{p_3v_2}{p_4},\; 2p_3v_1 - p_3v_2 - p_4v_1=0,
$$
and we are done. For the subcases $p_3=0$ or $p_4=0$ it works similarly.

Comment: Oh, it seems like you havent finished your solution,it is already very helpful for me, but please write it all

Comment: Oh, that's easy. If $p_3=0$, $p_4\neq 0$, then just $v_1=v_4=0$ and $v_2,v_3$ arbitrary, etc.